# Add multiple listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have

```js
function getProductAsHtmlString(product) {
  return `<article class="product">
    <form id="disappear">
      <fieldset></fieldset>

      <fieldset></fieldset>
      </form>
  </article>`;
}

function renderProducts(arrToRender) {
  const arrOfHtmlproducts = arrToRender.map(getProductAsHtmlString);
  const strOfHtmlproducts = arrOfHtmlproducts.join('\n');

  document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = strOfHtmlproducts;
}

renderProducts(products);

document.getElementById('toggleView').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("toggleView")) {
    //const parent = this.closest("section");
    this.querySelector("#disappear").style.display = "none";
    this.querySelector("#products").classList.toggle('grid-view');
  }
})
```

```html
<section>
  <button id="toggleView" class="toggleView">Change Array</button>
  <div id="products">
  </div>
</section>
```

But I'd like to run both function disappear and toggleProductLayout at once when 'toggleView' button is clicked.
How can I add multiple event listener?

Comment: `document.getElementById('toggleView').addEventListener('click', function(e) {disappear(e), toggleProductLayout(e)})`

Comment: @mplungjan The problem is there are many document.getElementById('products'). And only first #products applied disappear.

Comment: That is because you cannot have multiple identical IDs ID MUST be unique

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I mean there are many product in #products. But only first one product applied disappear.

Comment: 1. Change to class. 2. Find the nearest static container and delegate - something like this: `document.getElementById('containerID').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target; if (tgt.classList.contains("toggleView")) { const parent = this.closest("commonContainerTag"); parent.querySelector(". disappear").style.display="none"; parent.querySelector(".products").classList.toggle('grid-view');
} })`

Comment: where commonContainerTag is the div or table row or similar.

Comment: function getProductAsHtmlString(product){
 return `<article class="product"> <form id="disappear"></form></article>`;}

function renderProducts(arrToRender) {
  const arrOfHtmlproducts = arrToRender.map(getProductAsHtmlString);
  const strOfHtmlproducts = arrOfHtmlproducts.join('\n');

  document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = strOfHtmlproducts;
}

renderProducts(products);

Comment: document.getElementById('toggleView').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
  const tgt = e.target; 
  if (tgt.classList.contains("toggleView")) {
    const parent = this.closest("section");
    parent.querySelector("#disappear").style.display="none"; parent.querySelector("#products").classList.toggle('grid-view'); }
  })

Comment: @mplungjan
It still only first one product applied disappear. Because of my function getProductAsHtmlString(product)?

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting code in comments

Comment: @mplungjan I edited. Could you review it again?

Comment: You cannot have multiple items with the same ID - also what is arrToRender?

Comment: @mplungjan I understand!
I put ID on form. And arrToRender is just for use .map . Is it weird...? I'm too confused

Comment: Ok, I am off to bed. We want a [mcve] so please add an example of at least two rpodics so we can see what happens after the render